# Hyperlink disappears when form template saved

Tags: infopath, office-2007

I have an InfoPath form with several fields on, the problem is that one of the fields is a hyperlink and every time I save the form template, close it and open it again the hyperlink is gone. I know it saves the hyperlink because I use it in a workflow and the link is there, it only disappears when I open it in design view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem 
Remove Itemmetadata data source
edit itemmetadata.xml and ensure closing /> is on the same line as the last ows_xxx field
add new itemmetadata.xml etc.
Seemed to work for me !!